# TypeError Session

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, typeerror

This is the error I get:

> TypeError: SyncWebhook.*init*() missing 1 required positional argument: 'session'

This is the line:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if hook:
        webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name="Test")
        webhook_url = webhook.url
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            webhook = Webhook.from_url(str(webhook_url), adapter=SyncWebhook(session))
            while True:
                await webhook.send(spam_messages)

bot.run(token)
```

It's supposed to spam the message entered on the gui alongside while creating channels, it works and all but not the message part using webhooks.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an old code snippet with discord.py version >= 2.0.0, because this should work fine in the dpy version before 1.7.3.
Starting at dpy 2.0.0, `webhook.from_url` needs to remove `adapter` param and add `session` param (so it should be `session=session` in your case) or `client` param. (you need to pass in at least one of these two). If neither of these two are given, a `TypeError` will be raised. [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook%20from_url#discord.Webhook.from_url)